# Databricks Install Libraries through Libraries API is not working

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-rest-api

I'm trying to install libraries using this api: https:///api/2.0/libraries/install/
Here is the body:

```
   {
     "cluster_id": "<CLUSTER_ID>",
     "libraries": [
        {
          "pypi": {
                "package": "cryptography==3.4.7"
            }
        }
      ]
    }
```

And I'm getting the below response while my clusterId is valid and it's running

```
{
"error_code": "INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE",
"message": "Cluster <CLUSTER_ID> is terminated or does not exist"
}
```

Comment: Please check if the `CLUSTER_ID` referring to your cluster is in running state. If it is not, start the cluster and try again.

Comment: Yes I'd already verified that..CLUSTER_ID is correct and it is in running state.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have encountered same issue. This happened when I have 2 clusters with same name, but one is active, and the other is terminated. For some reason it is pulling the terminated cluster when used.

I have removed the cluster which is terminated and now it is working fine.